# Callisto custom dialog focus

Tags: callisto

How focus on element in custom dialog?

I try use *edGroupName.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard / Programmatic)* before and after open. Its not work.

```cs
//NewGroup is <callisto:CustomDialog>
NewGroup.IsOpen = true;

//edGroupName is <TextBox>
edGroupName.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `.IsOpen` the dialog doesn't open immediately -- it won't until you leave your method and control returns to the event loop.  So when you call `.Focus()` the text box is not actually visible yet.  You have to delay your `.Focus()` call until the text box is onscreen.

This works for me:

```
NewGroup.IsOpen = true;

await Task.Factory.StartNew( () => Dispatcher.RunAsync( CoreDispatcherPriority.Low,
                () => edGroupName.Focus( FocusState.Keyboard ) ) );
```